# Mercurial: Picking commits to be included in a release

Tags: mercurial

I have a local mercurial repository (for now) within which I have already made several commits, each commit is a self contained bug fix. Is it possible to pick which of the bug fixes (commits) I want to be included when it is time to build a release version of my application.

To elaborate, assuming A, B, C, D, and E are commits I have already done to my repository and each of them relates to a bug fix like so:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- working dir
```

I need to be able to for example pick which of the bug fixes will go into the release version (this depends on the time allocated for deployment as well as testing outcomes). So for example I might get a report saying the release should only contain bug fixes A, C and D.

Is it possible to construct a release version containing only the A, C and D commits (Keeping in mind that each commit is self contained and does not depend on the other commits to actually be there)?

Probably having a branch for each bug fix and then merging into a release branch is the easiest way to accomplish this (or is it not?), but the current situation at hand is as described above with no branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the normal work mode of Mercurial (or git).  A repository can only contain a changeset if it also contains all of that changeset's ancestors.  So you can't get D into a repo without also having A, B, and C in there.

So here's:

**What you Should have Done**

Control the parentage of your changesets.  Don't make C the parent of D just because you happen to have fixed D after C.  Before you fix a bug `hg update` to the previous release.

Imagine A was a release and B, C, and D, were all bug fixes.  If you do a loop like this:

```
foreach bug you have:
    hg update A
    ... fix bug ...
    hg commit 
    hg merge  # merges with the "other" head
```

then you'll end up with a graph like this:

```
---[A]----[B2]--[C2]--[D2]----
    |    /     /     /
    +-[B]     /     /
    |        /     /
    +-----[C]     /
    |            /
    +---------[D]
```

and now if you want to create a release with only, say, B and D in it you can do:

```
hg update B
hg merge D
```

and that creates a new head that has A + B + D but no C.

Tl;Dr: make a change's parent be as early in history as you can, not whatever happens to be *tip* at the time.

**What you can do Now**

That's the ideal, but fortunately it's no big thing.  You can never bring **exactly** D across without bringing C (because C's hash is part of the calculation of D's hash), but you can bring the work that's in D into a new head easily enough.  Here are some ways, any of which will work:

- hg export / hg import
- hg transplant
- hg graft (new in 2.0)
- hg rebase (only possible if you haven't yet pushed)

Any of those will let you bring that patch/delta that's in D over -- it will have a different hash ID and when some day you merge D in for real (using merge) you'll have duplicate work in two different changesets, but merge will figure it all out.

Comment: Notice that the workflow I show above has **anonymous branches** which are awesome.  They're not **named branches** which put new names into your repo for life.

Comment: I have to say, I wasn't aware of how to juggle anonymous branches like so. One question, what if after doing hg update B then hg merge D I want to get C into the next release. Would just be a matter of merging with C?

Comment: Yup, it's that easy.  `hg update B ; hg update C` would create a new head, let's call it BC, and then you can just do `hg update BC; hg merge C` and away you go.  Anonymous branches are **great**, but if they start to proliferate such that you can't tell what's in them you can always hang a **bookmark** on them (git-like lightweight names that advance with commit) or create a new clone and do the merges there.  New clones take up almost no space because they use hardlinks (even on windows).

Comment: Do people **really** work this way?  It sounds like a lot of hassle to me.  Making sure that your current fix really can be a child of A instead of B sounds quite error prone and a little bit too much effort.

Comment: Generally, yeah. Joel Spolsky does a good job of describing the process in his world-tour videos from last year.  It looks complicated in a diagram, but the TLDR captures it.  Just 'hg update' to where the bug was created (or to the first release that included it) and do the fix there.  As an extreme example I once needed to rename a product so I did 'hg update -r 0' (first commit ever) changed the PRODUCT_NAME constant and committed. Then I had a changeset I could 'hg merge' down into any release I wanted no matter how old. "Fix the bug where you made it" is easy to internalize.

Comment: What you are saying applies to a workflow when applying bug fixes right? +1 for pointing out the world-tour videos need to check em out.

Comment: I anchor bugfixes to where the bug was created, and when merging won't be too much work I anchor new features to the previous release.  That way come time for the next release you can gather any features you want and exclude any you don't.  If feature A and feature C both affect the same code a great deal then that's less practical (because you'll have to manually merge which _is_ coding and takes time) so having C be a 'kid' of A is fine, but in doing so you just need to know you won't be able to easily get C without A.

Answer (score 2):

If this was my tree and it hasn't been pushed anywhere, I'd (assuming an empty patch queue and MQ enabled):

```
hg qimport -g -r B:       # import revisions B and later into mq as "git" style patches
hg qpop -a                # unapply them all
hg qpush --move C         # Apply changes in C (--move rearranges the order)
hg qpush --move D         # Apply changes in D
hg qfin -a                # Convert C & D back to changesets 
hg push <release server>  # Push them out to the release branch
```

Then you can `hg qpush -a; hg qfin -a` to get B & E back into changesets.

Final Result:

```
---A---C---D---B---E
```

Advantages:

- Nobody needs know you didn't do things in this order to start with (evil grin)
- You could modify any of the change-sets whilst doing this

---

Alternatively, with graft in 2.0:

```
hg update -r A            # Goto rev A (no need to do anything special for A)
hg graft C                # Graft C on to a new anonymous branch
hg graft D                # Graft D
```

This will give you

```
---A---B---C---D---E
    \
     --C'--D'  <-You are here
```

An `hg push -r D'` should just push the new, cherry-picked, head.

You can then `hg merge` to get one head again with B and E included.

Advantages:

- Non destructive, so true history is kept, and no chance of loss if you muck up
- hg tags the new changesets with the hash of the original version, so totally trackable
- Probably a little simpler.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good solution, but I am not currently using MQ and haven't really used it before. Given the nature of the the fixes that I need to apply I am considering reverting back to rev A, and reapplying my fixes as indicated by the first answer by @Ry4an since it sounds like the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with MQ consider the second solution I give with graft. You could use graft to create the anonymous branches Ry4an talks about. `update A; graft C; update A; graft D; update A; graft E` and you've have your branches and no redoing the changes.

Answer (score 0):

While it's somehow strange way and release-policy, you can do it in different form. You have to manipulate with two main objects: changesets and branches

**Version 1**

You use two branches (default + f.e "release 1.0"). Default branch is mainline of your work - all changesets commited to *this* branch. At release-time, you branch first needed-for-release changeset into (new) branch, transplant or graft rest of *needed in release changesets* from default to this branch, head of release 1.0 will be prepared for release this way.

Next release will differ only in new branch name

**Version 2**

One branch used, MQ extension added. Variations:

- all changesets are MQ-pathes and only *needed for release* are applied to repo
- changesets are changesets, only *unwanted for release* converted to mq-pathes, later qfinish'ed and returned  to repo